# How to check if there is any selected row in gridControl?

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol, devexpress-gridcontrol

I'm beginner in using `DevExpress` tools.
I can not find any property, that shows the `gridControl's` row selections state, to my `if statement`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know the DevExpress grid control. However, most grid controls expose selection in one or both of two ways. Either something like `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedRow` on the grid (possibly in plural) or, a flag like `IsSelected` (or just `Selected`) on an individual row(s) (which is usually exposed as a `Rows` collection on the grid

Comment: Devexpress grid control can have many views. So, you can find the selected row in the grid control's views. I thing Grid View's `IsRowSelected` method or `GetSelectedRows` method that returns the selected rows in the grid will help you.

Comment: @muludag Yes, I didn't understand that gridView is part of the gridControl tool. With gridView now I can already check the number of selected rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ColumnView.SelectedRowsCount](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.SelectedRowsCount) property to return the number of selected rows/cards.

```
if (gridView1.SelectedRowsCount > 0) {    
    int[] selectedRowHandles = gridView1.GetSelectedRows();
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowHandles.Length; i++) {
      //... object rowObject = gridView1.GetRow(selectedRowHandles[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each Gridcontrol has a view , if your name the view for example Tableview then you can handle it easy, if you select a row it will return row index if no row selected it will return minus row number:

```
    int clickedRowHandle = Tableview.FocusedRowHandle;

                if (clickedRowHandle < 0)
                {
                    return;
                }else{
                     
                  //Do the action ...
                }
```